# Forge installation not working

Tags: java, minecraft

I want to install Forge for Minecraft but I'm getting errors and I don't know what they mean.  When I run `java -jar ~/Downloads/forge.jar` I get the following output:

```
We appear to be missing one or more essential library files.
You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:25)
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Edit: Same file works fine on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to execute the universal jar file, which is something you can't do.  From the Forge website, download the file labeled `Installer` rather than `Universal` then execute that.